# How to automate website UI testing

Tags: testing, website-features, automation

I would be rolling out many incremental updates/features to my website and I want to make sure no existing functionality is affected.

How can I automate this process? I know there are some tools that test the UI but am not sure which ones?

I would like to run a sanity test every week and be able to know if anything got broken.

Answer (score 11):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is good for automating this

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) that utilizes [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (a headless browser), especially the [tester module](http://casperjs.org/api.html#tester) for unit and functional testing!

You can do amazing things like screenshots of every aspect/position of your pages and continually run your very specific tests.

Nice example: Take a look at [screenshot-based regression testing](https://github.com/refinedlabs/screenspook).